# Brexit and biometrics at the border for EU citizens

Tags: eu-citizens, brexit

As of today, both in case of a no-deal, a yes-deal, or a delayed Brexit, will EU citizens have their fingerprints checked or taken upon entering the UK after 29 March 2019, either if they travel with a biometric passport or if they travel with their national ID card?

Comment: ‘Both’ cannot refer to three options

Comment: It's far from visa that Brexit will happen on 29th March. If it doesn't then the status quo prevails until it does. If it does.

Comment: @ReddHerring "*far from visa*" ??

Comment: @madhatter Oops - should have been 'far from clear'. I hate autocorrect!

Answer (score 2):

According to the UK government website, [only those with a UK biometric visa get their fingerprints checked at the border](https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/at-border-control).  Accordingly, it should be expected that only EU citizens who have a UK biometric visa will have their fingerprints checked at the border.

Answer (score 1):

People who want to live and work in the UK will most likely have to have a face scan:

> Instead ministers will require EU visitors to the UK to their faces scanned if they want to stay and work in the UK, The Sunday Telegraph can disclose.

- https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2017/10/08/face-scans-border-keep-track-eu-migrants-brexit/

As mentioned by @Phoog:

According to the UK government website, only those with a UK biometric visa get their fingerprints checked at the border. Accordingly, it should be expected that only EU citizens who have a UK biometric visa will have their fingerprints checked at the border.

Comment: That refers to residents, not visitors ("They were told this was the Home Office position on EU citizens already in the UK and not post-Brexit migrants").